# Repeating array values, if array is not long enough

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say i have an array like this:

```
$numbers = array("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
```

**What's the best way, to repeat values in php, if array have less than 5 elements?**
For example, If array is:

```
$numbers = array("one", "two", "three")
```

I want to get result like this:

```
$numbers = array("one", "two", "three","one", "two").
```

If array is with 2 elements, i want result like this:

```
$numbers = array("one", "two", "one", "two", "one").
```

If array is with 1 element, i want result like this:

```
$numbers = array("one", "one", "one", "one", "one").
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$numbers = array("one", "two");

$count = count($numbers);
for($i=$count; $i<=4;$i++){
    $numbers[] = $numbers[$i % $count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the array to have random additional values, you can use something like this :-

```
$numbers = array("one", "two", "three");
while(count($numbers) < 5)
{
    $numbers[] = $numbers[mt_rand(0,count($numbers))];
}
var_dump($numbers);
```